# v-for=вывести последние элементы массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Если сделать так то будет выводиться первые 25 сообщение, а новые сообщение уже будут не видны:
`<li class="chat-item" v-for="(data,index) in messages" v-if="index <= 24">`
так то же не получилось:
`v-for="data in messages.slice(Math.max(messages.length - 25, 1))"`
Можно, наверное, проверять и удалять сообщения в начале списка если больше 25, но есть навязчивая мысль, что это возможно сделать в шаблоне. Можно ли выводить только 25 последних элементов списка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

рекомендую сделать как вычисляемое свойство и использовать в v-for:

```
v-for="data in last25Messages"
...
computed: {
  last25Messages () {
    return this.messages(-25)
  }
}
```